# Dependency Injection in ApplicationEventHandler. Bug?

Tags: umbraco

Umbraco v7.5.8

I have bunch of problems with DI setup (shown below).

1) Neither OnApplicationInitialized, nor OnApplicationStarted (and other) events firing if constructor takes parameter(s).

2) Backoffice is broken. It's not possible to access a content node. Exception message is:
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ContentController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

```
    // Application handlers
    public class UmbracoApplicationEventHandler : IApplicationEventHandler
    {   
        private IMenuManager _menuManager;

        public UmbracoApplicationEventHandler(IMenuManager menuManager)
        {
            _menuManager = menuManager;
        }

        public void OnApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            ContentService.Saving += UpdateMenu;
        }

        private void UpdateMenu(IContentService sender, SaveEventArgs<IContent> saveEventArgs)
        {
            _menuManager.UpdateMenu();
        }
    }

// Unity config:
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IMenuManager, MenuManager>();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }

}

// Owin Startup:
public class UmbracoStandardOwinStartup : UmbracoDefaultOwinStartup
{
    public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //ensure the default options are configured
        base.Configuration(app);

        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/using-ioc.

You need to register and build your container on *OnApplicationStarted* event, not earlier if you want to make it work with Umbraco.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin. The approach in the article works OK with regular controllers. But it doesn't work with ApplicationEvenHandler, due to lack of supporting parametrized constructors (as I stated in topic description). Any ideas?

Comment: Why you want to inject your MenuManager straight to the ApplicationStartup class? I would create a service to handle this method(s) which would have it injected inside it's own constructor.

Comment: Because ApplicationStartup depends on MenuManager. For example, I'd like to trigger MenuManager.UpdateMenu() each time document gets published in CMS.

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski Were you able to make it work with a `ApplicationEvenHandler ` constructor taking a parameter? Or is Umbraco just shit when it comes to IoC? Seems to be the latter since there hasn't been a resolution on this since March 2017...

Comment: @Ash there is no issue with using IoC/DI with Umbraco, but it needs to follow the instruction posted above - those two classes are fired up when the app is starting and all the registrations should occur after that - no injections to those directly. Besides that - all fine :)

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski So essentially, can't have the constructor accept parameter(s)...which was your original requirement?

Comment: Of course, we can. We only can't have them in those 2 classes/interfaces which are starting before the IoC registration should occur.

Comment: @ivan-studenikin I repeated this word - studenikin - for many years, don't have idea where i got this word from... And now I see the person with such lastname, hahaha =)))